# How to pass argument from function to other function

Tags: php

I need to pass argument from one function to other function like in this example :

```
function myFunction($var){
    
    function otherFunction($var){
        // Do Somthing
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We should not define a function inside another function definition. You can define the `otherFunction` first and then call it from the `myFunction`.

```
function otherFunction($var){
   // Do Somthing
} 

function myFunction($var){
   otherFunction($var)
}
```